# Help needed finding System.Scripting.Actions library -- DynamicObject

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic-language-runtime, dynamic-languages

I downloaded a Dynamic sample to test. However, I seem to have run into some problem as I am unable to find one of the referenced libraries

System.Scripting.Actions

I figured it is possible the library may have been renamed or the classes moved to a different namespace. I tried using the Microsoft.Dynamic library but that did not yield acceptable result. Anyone have any idea what library I can actually find the System.Scripting.Actions objects in? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Are you using .net 4.0 DLR?

Try the "System.Dynamic" namespace located in the System.Core assembly.